# Newer Android APIs won't draw negative value rect

Tags: android, android-view, drawrect, ondraw

I had a canvas that was correctly displayed on older APIs. However, when I ran it on my newer tablet, the graphics weren't being drawn.

Here is a minimal test example:

```
  protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // .....
    // skipped paint initialization code ...

    canvas.drawRect(0, 0, 100, 100, redPaint);
    canvas.drawRect(100, 100, 200, 0, greenPaint);
    canvas.drawRect(200, 0, 300, 100, bluePaint);
    canvas.drawRect(300, 0, 400, 100, redPaint);
    canvas.drawRect(500, 0, 400, 100, bluePaint);
    canvas.drawRect(500, 0, 600, 100, greenPaint);
  }
```

Running this on older and new tablets will give very different results.

Older devices:
[RED][GREEN][BLUE][RED][BLUE][GREEN]

Newer devices:
[RED][SPACE][BLUE][RED][SPACE][GREEN]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that drawRect no longer works with negative values in newer APIs. To fix the problem, make sure values always go from lower to higher unless you have a specific reason for not wanting them to draw on new APIs.

Comment: this is not only the case on newer APIs but in my case depending on device. Nexus with API27 draws the rect, while Huawei with API25 did not

Comment: Interesting! Another reason never to do it the wrong way